# casus-belli tag?

Tags: discussion

> Casus belli is a Latin expression meaning "an act or event that provokes or is used to justify war" (literally, "a case of war").

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_belli

Might there have been enough questions on this to justify the tag?

Many if not most, admittedly, are closed as historical trivia. But I ended up wondering while trying to add it to [this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/43266/was-the-vietnam-war-preemptive).

Comment: You tell me. How many can you find?

Comment: @T.E.D.: Lots, from the looks of it. See e.g.: https://history.stackexchange.com/search?q=reason+war or https://history.stackexchange.com/search?q=reason+declare+war

Comment: Most of the results in "reason war" have nothing to do with the war's casus beli; "reason declare war" returns 5 questions, only one of which is actually about the reason for declaring war. That said, this can be a good idea because it's difficult to search for why a war started - as the very mixed search results demonstrate.